# Subtract mean from individual response, across separate data frames

Tags: r, dplyr

#### MY DATA STRUCTURE

My experiment is the effect of a condition (Placebo or Experimental) on power produced by individuals during three sprint efforts, measured across two seperate sessions.
One `data.frame` containes individual responses `(Individ)` and is structured as:

```
Individ <- data.frame(SubjectID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  Sprint = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  Session = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  Condition = c(Placebo, Placebo, Placebo, Placebo, Placebo, Placebo, Exper, Exper, Exper, Exper, Exper, Exper, Placebo, Placebo, Placebo, Placebo, Placebo, Placebo, Exper, Exper, Exper, Exper, Exper, Exper),
  Power = c(400, 250, 180, 500, 300, 450, 600, 512, 300, 500, 450, 200, 460, 254, 183, 540, 360, 420, 610, 514, 307, 508, 454, 201))
```

I obtained the mean power for each session via `library(dplyr)` and the following code to get my second `data.frame`:

```
AverageNMT <- summarise(group_by(Individ, Session, Condition), mean(Power, na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### MY PROBLEM

I wish to calculate the deltas for each individual's session. How do I subtract the mean power, grouping by session and condition, and adding in a new column? Expected output would be:

```
DeltaScores <- data.frame(SubjectID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
  Session = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
  Condition = c(Placebo, Placebo, Exper, Exper, Placebo, Placebo, Exper, Exper),
  DeltaPower = c(-11.1667, -11.6667, -3.16667, 11.16667, 11.66667, 189.1667, 2.166667))
```

Do I need to use `dplyr::mutate()`?
 Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution, but you need to merge in your summarized data to be able to calculate on it. You could also clean up your syntax via `%>%`

```
AverageNMT  <- Individ %>% group_by(Session, Condition) %>% summarize(mean_power= mean(Power, na.rm=TRUE))
ind2 <- merge(Individ, AverageNMT, by= c("Session", "Condition")) # name whatever you want
ind2 %>% group_by(SubjectID, Condition, Session) %>% summarize(DeltaPower= mean(Power) - mean(mean_power))

Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
Groups: SubjectID, Condition

  SubjectID Condition Session DeltaPower
1         1   Placebo       1 -11.166667
2         1   Placebo       2 -11.666667
3         2     Exper       1  -3.166667
4         2     Exper       2  -2.166667
5         3   Placebo       1  11.166667
6         3   Placebo       2  11.666667
7         4     Exper       1   3.166667
8         4     Exper       2   2.166667
```

Comment: If you are using `dplyr`, why not try `inner_join/left_join` etc. instead of `merge`

Answer (score 1):

I'm admittedly a little lost by the request but here's a data.table answer that might assist you a bit.

```
Individ <- data.frame(SubjectID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
                      Sprint = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                      Session = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                      Condition = c('Placebo', 'Placebo', 'Placebo', 'Placebo', 'Placebo', 'Placebo', 'Exper', 'Exper', 'Exper', 'Exper', 'Exper', 'Exper', 'Placebo', 'Placebo', 'Placebo', 'Placebo', 'Placebo', 'Placebo', 'Exper', 'Exper', 'Exper', 'Exper', 'Exper', 'Exper'),
                      Power = c(400, 250, 180, 500, 300, 450, 600, 512, 300, 500, 450, 200, 460, 254, 183, 540, 360, 420, 610, 514, 307, 508, 454, 201))


library(data.table)
setDT(Individ)
mPower=mean(Individ$Power) #getting the mean to subtract
DeltaScores<-Individ[,j=list(
    DeltaPower = mean(Power)-mPower
),by=.( SubjectID,Session, Condition)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(Rmisc)
dfc1<-summarySE(Individ, measurevar = "Power",groupvars = c("Condition","Session"))
dfc2<-summarySE(Individ, measurevar = "Power",groupvars = c("Condition","Session","SubjectID"))
dfc3 <- dfc2

for (i in 1:nrow(dfc2)) {
        dfc2$Power[i] <- dfc2$Power[i] - dfc1$Power[which(dfc1$Condition == dfc2$Condition[i] & dfc1$Session == dfc2$Session[i])]
}

> dfc2
  Condition Session SubjectID N      Power        sd       se       ci
1     Exper       1         2 3  -3.166667 154.21198 89.03433 383.0838
2     Exper       1         4 3   3.166667 154.85154 89.40358 384.6726
3     Exper       2         2 3  -2.166667 160.72751 92.79607 399.2693
4     Exper       2         4 3   2.166667 163.89733 94.62617 407.1435
5   Placebo       1         1 3 -11.166667 112.39810 64.89307 279.2124
6   Placebo       1         3 3  11.166667 143.87842 83.06825 357.4138
7   Placebo       2         1 3 -11.666667 104.08330 60.09252 258.5573
8   Placebo       2         3 3  11.666667  91.65151 52.91503 227.6750
```

check the output of `dfc1 dfc2 dfc3` and see if it's correct